# Fill the series with value of most recent date and monthly percentage change in pandas dataframe - python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data with value of most recent date (1-31-2018) and monthly percentage change. I need to fill the value of previous dates in series. Sample data below

> Dataframe df:

```
 Date          pct_change
 7/31/2017  99.944%
 8/31/2017  100.462%
 9/30/2017  100.552%
 10/31/2017 100.158%
 11/30/2017 100.103%
 12/31/2017 100.308%
 1/31/2018  100.000%


 print(latest_CPI_value)
 105.75
```

Expected Output:

```
 Date          pct_change   CPI_value
 7/31/2017  99.944%      104.0940789
 8/31/2017  100.462%     104.5745771
 9/30/2017  100.552%     105.1515151
 10/31/2017 100.158%     105.3174442
 11/30/2017 100.103%     105.4257105
 12/31/2017 100.308%     105.75
 1/31/2018  100.000%     105.75
```

Can anyone plz help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We need convert those % to numeric then we using `cumprod`

```
df['pct_change'] = pd.to_numeric(df['pct_change'].str[:-1])

s = (df['pct_change']/100).cumprod()

s*105.75/s.iloc[-1]

Out[509]: 
0    104.092523
1    104.573430
2    105.150676
3    105.316814
4    105.425290
5    105.750000
6    105.750000
Name: pct_change, dtype: float64
```

Comment: @ArvinthKumar yw :-)